# VMWare python API : How to access cpu load average?

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I'm trying to get the load average of my ESX, using python script et pyVmomi.

I cannot find the numbers `1.71, 1.72, 1.72` from the API, as described in the commands below. Any clues ?

```
# ssh my-esx
[root@my-esx:~] uptime
12:07:54 up 8 days, 21:02:09, load average: 1.71, 1.72, 1.72

[root@my-esx:~] uname -a
VMkernel my-esx 6.0.0 #1 SMP Release build-3073146 Sep 16 2015 04:08:47 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 ESXi
```

For now, I get the `overallCpuUsage` as [described here](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22/fa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc/doc/index.html#link11cca3d4c4e4103a5f5c860ab81da1944667f777;vim.host.Summary.QuickStats.html%23overallCpuUsage), but this data is more like a percentage of allocated Mhz. It cannot be compared to the classic "linux load average".

It's important for me, because our monitoring page compare cpu load of ESXs server and Linux server.